# Can we compare a string with == to an empty value

Tags: java

Lets say we have a string in java. Can we compare this string to `""` using the `==`?
For example:

```
String myString = "";
if(myString == "");
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: You can but it won't return correct result. Use `"".equals(myString)` instead.

Comment: There is nothing specific to `""` - in particular `new String("") == ""` will return false.

Comment: we can, but it is always better to use isEmpty() method like myString.isEmpty()

Comment: @f1sh - Yes I tried it and it was working fine.But then I read somewhere that it does not always give the right results.So I wanted to know the reason of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can (insofar that compilation will pass), although you will probably not get the result you expect since using `==` will compare *references* **not** *contents*.

My favourite way is to use the *Yoda Expression* `"".equals(myString)` since then you don't need to pre-test `myString` for `null`.

Else you could use `myString.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.